# Downloading while processing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I have the following scenario, a timer every x minutes:

1. download an item to work from a rest service (made in php)
2. run a process batch to elaborate item

Now the application is fully functional, but I want to speedup the entire process downloading another item (if present in the rest service) while the application is processing one.

I think that I need a buffer/queue to accomplish this, like BlockingCollection, but I've no idea how to use it.

What's the right way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a function which checks for new files to download. Have this function start as its own background thread that runs in an infinite loop, checking for new downloads in each iteration. If it finds any files that need downloading, call a separate function to download the file as a new thread. This new download function can then call the processing function as yet another thread once the file finishes downloading. With this approach you will be running all tasks in parallel for multiple files if needed.

Functions can be started as new threads by doing this

```
Thread thread = new Thread(FunctionName);
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive"). Then you can do this:

```
var x_minutes = 5;

var query =
    from t in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(x_minutes))
    from i in Observable.Start(() => DownloadAnItem())
    from e in Observable.Start(() => ElaborateItem(i))
    select new { i, e };

var subscription =
    query.Subscribe(x =>
    {
        // Do something with each `x.i` & `x.e`
    });
```

Multi-threaded and simple.

If you want to stop processing then just call `subscription.Dispose()`.